# Return this as inherited type

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am creating a finite state machine class, but am running into some trouble returning `this` as the correct type.

The parent class

```
public class FsmState<StateAsEnum, SelfClass> where StateAsEnum : Enum
{
    protected SelfClass NextState;

    public StateAsEnum StateName { get; protected set; }

    public NpcState Process()
    {
        if (Stage == FsmStage.Enter) Enter();
        if (Stage == FsmStage.Update) StateUpdate();

        if (Stage == FsmStage.Exit)
        {
            Exit();
            return NextState;
        }

        return this; //the trouble.
    }
}
```

I can not ensure that `SelfClass` and the type `FsmState` are the same. When I inherit from  this class I would like to return `this` as the inherited class.

```
class NpcState : FsmState<NpcState.States, NpcState>
{
     Process();
}
```

This guy is used in

```
NpcState currentState 

loop 
{
      currentState = currentState.Process();
}
```

Comment: Did you try `return (SelfClass)this;`

Comment: Why does your generic parent class return a specific subclass instance from Process?

Comment: @Fabio yes, because of the generic T, it is not allowed. `Cannot cast FsmState<A,B> to SelfCast `.

Comment: @CaiusJard it is convenient as can be seen in the loop. The Above question also answers why I cannot pass the parent class, generics do

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. It doesn't look nice but the casting helped when I applied recursive inheritance on the types.

```
public class FsmState<StateAsEnum, SelfClass> where StateAsEnum : Enum where SelfClass : FsmState<StateAsEnum,SelfClass>

public SelfClass Process()
    {
        ...
    
        return (SelfClass) this;
    }
```

It's not pretty but it works.

Comment: This approach called "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" ;)